# Free Proxy Paperbus makes browser not work

Tags: proxy

I installed Paperbus Phttp://www.paperb.us/ but when I turn it on my browsers don't work at all, it just loads and loads and doesn't load the websites.

Comment: Are you running another proxy server on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Likely you haven't configured the proxy correctly, or the proxy you have selected is not open/down at the moment.

Comment: i did not know you had to configure or choose a proxy for this. How do you do that?